# What viewport meta tag can I use to allow for changing orientation while restricting user zooming?

Tags: ios, html, responsive-design, viewport, orientation-changes

I am having a problem finding the right viewport meta tag to use for a responsive site while restricting user scaling.

Currently I am using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

I am getting some really weird issues on my iPad2. Upon orientation change, the layout for the previous orientation, including elements that should be hidden by media queries, is taken and posted over-top of the correct layout.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks,

[image: Orientation Problems]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just this and nothing else, remove the rest

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Thanks! Still allows zooming though.

Comment: Zooming is restricted with the addition of "user-scalable=no" Thanks!